# Fooling an app about mouse location

Tags: c#, java, winapi, mouseevent, user32

First of all if there is any language-specific solutions to this that are only possible in c++/c#/java etc. please say so because im fine with using any one.
Currently I'm trying to click a button in an app that is at background, and I can manage the "click" part using send/post message. Like so:

```
            SendMessage(Window, 0x201, 0, 700 * 0x10000 + 700);
```

0x201 here is left mouse button down and supposedly location should be 700, 700

**However, when I send that message the app im trying to fool acts based on my current mouse position and not 700,700.**

I believe this is due to the fact that the app im trying to fool looks for current mouse position. any way to fool that ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't implement this with `SendMessage`, you're too late in the process there - the system has already processed all kinds of things and determined which message to send once it gets to message queues. Sending raw click events in there will only confuse it more.

Instead you should use [SendInput Win32 API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It emulates mouse (and other input device) behaviours at a higher level, and then lets the system take care of processing the resulting messages *as if a real mouse caused them*. It will thus by definition fool everyone, because there's nothing to fool - the mouse really moved to the given location for all intents and purposes.

You could also use the for this purpose more straightforward [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call, but it's formally deprecated so `SendInput` is preferred.

Comment: the problem here is, if I use sendinput I would be using actual mouse and not fooling the app. While doing so, my app would render computer useless since it uses mouse itself and the "user" would be unable to do whatever they like at the moment.

Comment: The only real alternative is installing [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(v=vs.60).aspx). It allows you to inspect *exactly* which messages are broadcast in which order by an action, for example a mouseclick. From this log you should then be able to replay the exact required sequence.

Comment: would it differ from OS to OS or are they same ?(as in windows) also, how do I replay exact sequence ? by sendmessage ?

Comment: I have tried what you have said and spy++ reports wm_lbuttonups and downs. othing extraordinory. however my problem is that this program seems to also check actual windows cursor positions. any advice ?

Comment: Well there's only 2 options: control the mouse with `SendInput`, or emulate its results with `SendMessage`. If the second doesn't work properly, you're confined to the first. It's still fooling the app, you're just taking over part of the system at a more fundamental level than it can see.